# Sort in linear time comparison based

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm given the task to write pseudocode for a comparison based algorithm that unshuffles an array, that was first sorted and then shuffled with the following algorithm. The algorithm running time needs to be theta(n).

```
Shuffle(int[] A) 
n1 = A.length+1 / 2 // floordiv
n2=A.lenght-n1
L = L[n1]
R = R[n2]
L[1...n1] = A[1...n1]
R[1...n2] = A[n1+1...A.length]
i=j=1;
for k=1 to A.length do
  b=Random(0,1)  // returns 0 or 1 equally likely
  if(b == 0 and i<= n1) or j>n2 then
     A[k] = L[i]
     i++;
  else
     A[k] = R[j]
     j++;
```

I've found that after shuffeling A every Item with index i from the left Subarry L lies inbetween A'[i...n2+i].
And every Item with index i from the right Subarray R lies inbetween A'[i-n2...i].
I know that the solution involves finding the median but i don't understand how that's gonna help.

I also know about Selection in worstcase linear time ( from Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms) but how do i combine this to get the right algorithm?

Comment: This question is better suited for CS stackexchange than SO.

Comment: *but i don't understand how that's gonna help*. Here's a hint: the values in the shuffled array are created by randomly choosing values either from `L` or `R` array. Those arrays are created based on the median of the original array. You can utilize this fact to undo the shuffling by recreating `R` and `L` from the shuffled array.

Comment: Thanks,  I was about to post it on SO but i need to wait for 40min.

Comment: The original median lies after shuffeling in either the last position of L' or in R'. I can therefore recreate R and L by comparing to the median, but R and L are still unsorted. In order to sort now L and R i would surpass theta(n), wouldn't I?

Comment: The shuffled array does not disrupt the order of elements in `R` or `L`. It just mixes them together. You only need the median to recreate each one again.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. That was the missing piece in the puzzle :)

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shuffled array does not disrupt the order of the elements in `R` or `L` arrays. Both of them are contained in the shuffled array but their elements are interleaved.

Knowing this fact, you can calculate the median (can be done in linear time) and then use it to recreate `R` and `L` again thus undoing the shuffling.